# Implementing vue-social-sharing in vuetify causes error

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to implement vue-social-sharing in my project in vuetify and it causes error. I want to implement it inside a modal popup.

What I have in main.js is this:

```
import SocialSharing from 'vue-social-sharing';

Vue.use(SocialSharing);
```

My modal:

```
   <v-dialog
    v-model="shareDialog"
    persistent
    max-width="800px"
  >
    <v-card>
      <div class="pa-1">
        <network
          network="email"
          class="pointer inline pa-1"
        >
          <span>
            <i
              class="fas fa-envelope-square"
              style="font-size: 18px"
            />
            Email
          </span>
        </network>
        <network
          network="facebook"
          class="pointer inline pa-1"
        >
          <span>
            <i
              class="fab fa-facebook-square"
              style="font-size: 18px"
            />
            Facebook
          </span>
        </network>
        <network
          network="linkedin"
          class="pointer inline pa-1"
        >
          <span>
            <i
              class="fab fa-linkedin"
              style="font-size: 18px"
            />
            LinkedIn
          </span>
        </network>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
```

Declared in data:

```
 data: () => ({
shareDialog: false,
 })
```

Methods to close and open the modal:

```
  open(data) {
  this.shareDialog = true;
  }

close() {
  this.shareDialog = false;
},
```

And the error that occurs is this:

[image]

If I click the icons that send me nowhere too :/

The modal opened:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing it looks like you're using the wrong component? You have `<network />` but it should be `<ShareNetwork />`